# Dynamic field in table Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

BootstrapVue has the option to create a dynamic table but for Vuetify I do not see this option.
In Boostrap Vue it looks like this:

```
 <b-table id = "tableh": items = "cards": fields = "fields": filter = "filter": current-page = "currentPage": per-page = "perPage"
    <template class = "link" slot = "index" slot-scope = "cards">
    <p style = "margin: 0"> {{cards.item.id}} </ p>
    </ Template>
</b-table>
```

And all the fields in the table are dynamically populated. This option in Vuetify does not work, does anyone know an alternative.
The tables have many fields and for a long time they take me away from them.

Comment: what do you mean as "dynamic"? pass async function as table prop or what? vuetify has data-table which is pretty similar to bootstrap table https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/data-tables

Comment: Okey example, I want same table as BootstrapVue (code above) , I can't do it?